# JavaScript redirect based on probability

Tags: javascript, redirect, probability

I'm trying to create a webpage that will always redirect users to other webpages. It will increase the probability of redirecting users to 1 of 30 pages, using JavaScript, based on scores that are imported from a MySQL database.

For example, there will be 30 possible pages that a user could be redirected to (A1.html, A2.html, A3.html...and so on).

So, for example, if the MySQL database information for a user was:

A1 = 0, A2 = 6, A3 = 10, A4 = 8

The user would have no chance of being redirected to A1.htm, a moderate chance of being redirected to A2.htm, a higher chance of being redirected to A4.htm, and a high chance of being redirected to A3.htm.

Getting the MySQL data into the webpage isn't the issue, I'm just not finding myself able to thin of a way to write some JavaScript that will achieve this result. I've been playing around with this all day, but I don't have any working solution.

If anyone can help me out, I'd be massively grateful. Many thanks! :)

Comment: Interesting problem! My offhand take on it would be to sum A1 through A4 (=24), then go through a loop that number of times using math.random() to fill a 24 element array by saving the first six .2 answers, first ten .3 answers, first eight .4 answers. I'd then get a final random number to decide which of the 24 members of the array to use. I'm not a theoretical mathematician so I have no idea if the result would be truly random.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array, with a number of entries based on the number of preferences and then insert a random number between 0 and the number of elements - 1. Something like:

```
var likeness=[A2,..(6 times), 
A3,...(10 times),
A4,...(8 times)]; //A1 is 0 so no entry for him

var totalElements=likeness.length;
```

then choose random number between 0 and the number of elements:

```
var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*totalElements);
```

last you retrieve the intended url

```
var urlRedirect=likeness[randomNumber];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i<totalURLs; i++) {
    likes = getLikes(i);
    destinationURL = getURL(i);

    for(var ii=0; ii<likes; ii++) {
        probabilityField.push( destinationURL );
    }
}

var chance=Math.floor( Math.random() * probabilityField.length );

window.location.replace( probabilityField[chance] );
```